# Repeating labels even if I set to "No repeat" in Placement

Tags: qgis, labeling

In QGIS, I'm working on a map with the contours of a certain location. For the contour labels I used a fixed position with the "Label Toolbar". In the settings of the labels, in "Placement" I set it to "No repeat". Even so some labels are still repeating, in Print Layout as well. Now how can I place only one label for each feature in my drawing?

Repeating labels in the project:
[image]

Repeating labels in Print Layout:
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm they are the same features? Looks like another feature having the same elevation. If they have the same elevation, you can dissolve them by elevation-attribute.

Comment: Yes they're the same features, each elevation on an individual polyline, they just happen to be really extensive polylines that I put behind an Inverted polygon to delimit the area that I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
if(array_agg($id,group_by:="ELEV")[0] = $id,"ELEV",'')
```

as label value.

But keep in mind this costs some calcuation and may slow down rendering especially on large layers.

How it works: the expression generates an array of each feature-id, grouping the ones together having the same elevation. Now it checks for each feature if it is the first one in the array (of each elevation) and only labels the feature if so, otherwise not.